# Dynamically updating html table with JSON using jQuery for complex object

Tags: jquery, json

I am still new to JSON/jQuery.

I need some quick guidance on how to dynamically populate Html table on the client. My table has fixed columns, but rows grow dynamically depending on data retreived.

Say I have a Web Method on the server (`GetActiveUsers`) that is returning, say n- users.
I am using this sql:

```
select userId, Title,Surname,FirstName from Users where status=1
```

Please give me sample code

**Edit**

I have solution for this on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c)
Thanks guys

Comment: what platform are you using? PHP? ASP.net mvc?

Comment: could you post an example of the JSON being returned to you?

Comment: @oo I am using Asp.net forms
@Russ I do not have sample JSON, I am actually keen to suggestion of the possible JSON format

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect application of **jQote** THE jQuery javascript templating engine.
You can fetch it from here: http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugin/jqote.

As an example consider the following:

```
// Example of your json data ... an array of user objects
[{
    "Title": "Dr.",
    "Surname": "House",
    "Firstname": "Geronimo"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Mr.",
    "Surname": "Franklin",
    "Firstname": "Benjamin"
  }
]
```

Now here's the template you would define in your HTML (or whatever output file you have):

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <![CDATA[
        <tr>
            <td class="no"><%= j+1 %></td>
            <td class="title"><%= this.Title %></td>
            <td class="user"><%= this.Firstname + " " + this.Surname %></td>
        </tr>
    ]]>
</script>
```

So, we're almost done. Let's define our containing table and call jQote on the json data
to magically fill the table.

```
... your markup ...

<table id="users"></table>

... more markup ...

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsondata = xxx // get your data somehow

    // Now call jQote on the template providing your json data
    $('#template').jqote(jsondata).appendTo($('#users'));
</script>
```

That's all (well it's just the beginning, jQote is way more powerfull than I could tell you here).

Hope you like it, give it a try.

BTW: The use of  as your template's container is perfectly legal markup. And browsers will not display it in any case.

Comment: Took me a while to work out how to use json from an ajax call to feed jqote.  Here's (one) way:     var jsondata = $.getJSON('/path/to/call/',
        function(data) {
            row = $('#template').jqote(data);
            $('#mytable > tbody:last').append(row);
            
        });