# Uncaught TypeError jqute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treetable, jqote

I am trying to make a really simple html tableTree. I have no experience regarding html/javascript programming so I'm traversing google to find examples on what I'm trying to achive.

I am currently trying to find an easy way to pass a json file into an html document, and I have been successfull by doing that code part my self and using ajax and jquery.

However I have found an example using jqote2, though implementing this example gives me an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". I guess I'm missing something though i cannot figure out what so I'm hoping I could get some assistance here :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqote2/jquery.jqote2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/html" id="template">
  <![CDATA[
    <tr>
      <td class="no"><%= j+1 %></td>
      <td class="title"><%= this.Title %></td>
    </tr>
  ]]>
  </script> 
  <!-- 2 load the theme CSS file -->
  <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var jsondata = [{"Title": "Dr.", "Surname": "House", "Firstname":  "Geronimo"},{"Title": "Mr.", "Surname": "Franklin", "Firstname": "Benjamin"}];
    // Now call jQote on the template providing your json data
    $('#template').jqote(jsondata).appendTo($('#users'));
  </script>

  <div>
    <table id="users"></table>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've build this code based on the example found at http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugin/jqote/

When running this code i get the error on

```
$('#template').jqote(jsondata).appendTo($('#users'));
```

So what am I missing :) I've check and the included files does exist and the path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a problem in the CData section 
Characters like "<" and "&" are illegal in XML elements.

"<" will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of a new element.

"&" will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of an character entity.

Some text, like JavaScript code, contains a lot of "<" or "&" characters. To avoid errors script code can be defined as CDATA.

Everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.
moveover you can't write string as you did

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

drawing a table from json object would go like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- 2 load the theme CSS file -->
  <title>Test</title>
  </head>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var jsondata = [{"Title": "Dr.", "Surname": "House", "Firstname":  "Geronimo"},{"Title": "Mr.", "Surname": "Franklin", "Firstname": "Benjamin"}];
    // Now call jQote on the template providing your json data

    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $.each( jsondata, function( key, value ) {
            $.each( value, function( k, v ) {
                    $("#"+k).html(v);

            });
    });
});

  </script>

   <body>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td id="Title"></td>
  <td id="Surname"></td>
  <td id="House"></td>
  <td id="Firstname"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

the first loop will cut down the object into arrays , the second one will let you get the keys and values and then do what you want with them ^_^ hope this help

Comment: what parser are we talking about here becuase as i understand it <script type="text/html" id="template"> should cloak it so the code is not passed before i use it.  I've also used this to guide me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213216/dynamically-updating-html-table-with-json-using-jquery-for-complex-object

Comment: ok maybe you are trying a hard way to do something can be done easily without involving CDATA tags ..would you please explain what are you aiming to do :)

Comment: ok i got it, you want to draw HTML table using data from json ? and assign each value in its corresponding cell ?

Comment: I aming at using jQuery treetable to represent my data. and i have a program that creates a json file during run time, i want this file to be leaded dynamically into the treetable.

Comment: I am also aiming to keep my code as simple as possible. nothing fancy

Comment: ok i have never used jqote however, in order to properly draw a table dynamically from data coming from json , the magic part will be assigning the key of each json element as id for its corresponding cell...then use .each function to loop the coming json data, then use something like $("#"+JSONKEY).val();

Comment: like this <table><tr><td id="Title"></td><td id="Surname"></td><td id="Firstname"></td></tr></table> note that ids are the same keys in your json , the .each() function loop through the json arrays and just use the $("#"+key).val(); it will draw them without using jqoutes :D

Comment: this is more simple something like  $.each( jsondata, function( key, val ) {
    $("#".key).val();
  });

Comment: Will need to try it but it looks like what I'm aiming for. I do though have one more question. Using the `$("#"+k).html(v);` How do i change an attribute instead of a value. to dynamically populate my table i need to change **data-tt-id** in the `<tr data-tt-id="1">` using values from my json data.

Comment: then use another function to draw your table in a for loop or something

Comment: to change the attribute use .attr("yourattribute").val()

Comment: something like this $("#id of tag you want to change its attribute).attr("theattribute you want to change").val('the new value');