# Encode object to JSON

Tags: c#, json

Hoping I don't have to reinvent the wheel here but does anyone know if there is a class in C# similar to the one supplied by Adobe for AS3 to convert a generic object to a JSON string?

For example, when I encode an array of objects.

```
new JSONEncoder(arr).getString();
```

Output:

```
[
    {"type":"mobile","number":"02-8988-5566"},
    {"type":"mobile","number":"02-8988-5566"}
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create JSON string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

in C#:

```
var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = jsonSerializer.Serialize(yourCustomObject);
```

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` is a pain to use. You should give a try to [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

Comment: Add **System.Web.Extensions** into References see [https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx]

Answer (score 16):

I recommand using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json). It's not part of .Net's the core libraries, but it is very widely used, including by a lot of Microsoft's products. Also it's the single most used [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). And it's both easier to use than `JavaScriptSerializer` and more efficient.

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObjet);

var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(jsonString);
```

Comment: I belive it is "SerializeObject" and not "Serialize" in the latest version

Comment: I also had to add `.ToString()` at the end or it produced an error. `var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(jsonString.ToString());`

Comment: @guitarlass : that's pretty weird. jsonString should be a string from the start!

Comment: yeah it is, i even printed it to test. yet i had to convert it before deserializing

Comment: It also doesn't have the serialization problems that are in Microsoft's Json.Encode() and JavaScriptSerializer().

Answer (score 3):

The following methods work well for me (using the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)):

```
public static T FromJson<T>(string input)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Deserialize<T>(input);
}

public static string ToJson(object input)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(input);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this out [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx).

> Use the DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize and deserialize data in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format. This serialization engine converts JSON data into instances of .NET Framework types and back into JSON data