# read collection within collection in linq

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

i need to read a collection within collection and return json result either my linq or feach?

```
from col1 in collection1 select new{}{col1.field1, col1.field2, }
```

Read collection2 in `col1` and do sum of numeric field present for each row and return to `json`.

Comment: This question is not clear enough.  Please clarify and add detail.

Answer (score 0):

If I've read and deciphered your question correctly, I think you are looking for:

```
var collectionOfSums = from col1 in collection1
                       select new {
                         SumOfField1 = field1.Sum(),
                         SumOfField2 = field2.Sum(),
                         ...
                         SumOfFieldN = fieldN.Sum()
                       };
```

I am assuming that the `field1`, `field2`, ... `fieldN` are a known set.  Then use whatever technology you prefer to `JSON`-ify `collectionOfSums`.

Comment: how do I read from collection2 which is present within collection1?

Comment: its like:
collection1[0] //o: index
-----Collection2[2]//2 number of rows
collection1[1]//1: index
-----collection2[4] //4 number of rows

Comment: So this is a two-dimensional array?

Comment: its collection within collection

Comment: Then I think you are better off with a simple pair of loops rather than LINQ.

Comment: I don't know How do I return JSON return.

Comment: Read this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287399/encode-object-to-json)