# Ajax call successful, but error block is executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to save a post to my database which it does, however the ajax error block is executing. It states ok in its response though so I looked around on some of the other questions and it seemed like I wasn't returning a Json object so I tried a few things:

Creating a NameValule variable and adding ("Success","true") and converting it to Json by Json.Encode(NameValue);

Returning a string in the format of Json:"{ \"Result\":[{\"Success\":\"true\"}]}";

Changing the dataType to "text json" "text/json"

The error block still executes for some reason, any ideas?

```
//Save it all in an object to be passed in ajax 
    var Post = {
        Id: postID,
        Title: postTitle.val(),
        Author: postAuthor,
        Date: postDate,
        Content: postContent.val(),
        metaDescription: metaDescription.val(),
        metaKeywords: metaKeywords.val(),
        metaID: metaId.text(),
        Page: $(document).attr('title')
    };
//save to database 
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: "text json",
            data: { data: JSON.stringify(Post) },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("result: " + result);
                if (result == "Success") {
                   // postContent.append("<br/><p>Edit Successful!</p>");
                    alert('Edit successfull');
                   //window.location.replace(window.location.href);
                }
                else {
                    postContent.replaceWith("<div>" + result + "</div>");
                }                    
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) { 
                console.log('ajax error = ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
```

Here is the response page:

```
@using WebMatrix.Data; 
@functions{
    public string EditPost()
    {
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var post = Request.Unvalidated["data"];
        var result = Json.Decode(post);
        var error = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

        /*        Id: postID,
                    Title: postTitle,
                    Author: postAuthor,
                    Date: postDate,
                    Content: afterEdit,
                    Page: $(document).attr('title')
                    */
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result["Id"]))
        {
            error.Add("Error", "Id empty");
            return Json.Encode(error);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result["Author"]))
        {
            error.Add("Error", "Author empty");
            return Json.Encode(error);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result["Content"]))
        {
            error.Add("Error", "Content empty");
            return Json.Encode(error);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result["Date"]))
        {
            error.Add("Error", "Date empty");
            return Json.Encode(error);
        }
        //Page and Title only ones that can be empty
        var cmd = "UPDATE Posts SET ID='" + result["Id"]
                + "',Author='" + result["Author"]
                + "',Content='" + result["Content"]
                + "',Date='" + result["Date"]
                + "',Title='" + result["Title"]
                + "',Page='" + result["Page"]
                + "' WHERE ID='" + result["Id"] + "';";
        try { db.Execute(cmd); }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error.Add("Error",e.Message);
            return Json.Encode(error);
        }


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result["metaDescription"]))
        {
            error.Add("Error", "metaDescription empty");
            return Json.Encode(error);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result["metaKeywords"]))
        {
            error.Add("Error", "metaKeywords empty");
            return Json.Encode(error);
        }
        //Post was edited successfully add/update meta info
        int parseResult = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(result["metaID"], out parseResult);
        if (parseResult > 0)//metaID is supplied
        {
            cmd = "UPDATE MetaInfo SET Description='" + result["metaDescription"]
             + "',Keywords='" + result["metaKeywords"]
             + "',postID='" + result["Id"]
             + "' WHERE ID='" + result["metaID"] + "';";
        }
        else //metaID is not supplied
        {
            cmd = "INSERT INTO MetaInfo (Description,Keywords,postID) VALUES('"
            + result["metaDescription"] + "','"
            + result["metaKeywords"] + "','"
            + result["Id"] + "');";
        }
        try
        {
            db.Execute(cmd);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error.Add("Error",e.Message);
            return Json.Encode(error);
        }
        //End Update meta info 
        error.Add("Success", "true");
        return Json.Encode(error); //"{ \"Result\":[{\"Success\":\"true\"}]}";
    }
}
 @{
 var result = EditPost(); 
 } 
 @result
```

Comment: You mean like I have? "success: function (result) { console.log("result: " + result);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that may have this same problem here was how I finally solved it: Just use Html.Raw(result) to send back only the json instead of extra stuff that gets added for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be sure without knowing the requirements for the url.  My guess would be that the data property is the reason you're off.  I'm guess `Post` is an object defined elsewhere.  When you send your request, the server will likely interpret the data field as an object not a string. Try to change `{data: JSON.stringify(Post)}` to just `JSON.stringify(Post)`

Comment: If I do that then I get a new error on the request page that says the value cannot be null

Comment: what is the original error? You could always try to use the shorthand method and use promises.  $.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )

Comment: you probably have this, but just make sure your response is sending JSON as well.. res.json(data)

Answer (score 0):

try with adding  async: true, line after type: 'POST',

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your JSON response.

```
"{ \"Result\":[{\"Success\":\"true\"}]}";
```

There added slashes before double quotes(").

You can see the actual error thrown by jQuery using below updated error block:

```
error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        console.log(errorThrown )
```

Solution:

Remove slashes from your response try response like below:

```
'{ "Result":[{"Success":"true"}]}'
```

Hope this will help you.

Regards,

Comment: I know about the escaped quotes as I am using C# to respond to the request. The errorThrown says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token &" I'm not sure where the & is coming from though

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token & means you are getting & in the response. If so try removing it as well

Comment: The problem must be with the response so I added it in the question. There is no & in the result when I debug just Json so I can't remove it :(

Comment: Ok, have a look at this question and its selected answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287399/encode-object-to-json