# JSON encode URLs in C# like what PHP does

Tags: c#, php, json, string

When I use `json_encode` function in PHP to encode an Object in json format, it will change urls in output to an string with escape characters like `http:\/\/example.com\/apps\/images\/image01.jpg` however C# return a url as is i.e. `http://example.com/apps/images/image01.jpg` and will not add any escape characters. Since I'm going to implement a web-service just same as my old PHP web service, I want to know how can I encode a url string in C# to be the same as PHP string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode object to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287399/encode-object-to-json)

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything. If you write your string i.e. to file (or console) from `PHP` and from `C#` you will get the same results without changing anything.

If you really want to replace `/` by `\/` use `String.Replace()` method:

```
string likePhp = strCSharp.Replace("/", @"\/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need escaped slashes, so tell PHP not to escape them with `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`.  Why try and hack the C# JSON to escape the slashes when it's not needed.:

```
echo json_encode('http://example.com/apps/images/image01.jpg', JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Yields:

```
http://example.com/apps/images/image01.jpg
```

Comment: @DavidL: Yes I did. The echo is an example obviouslyshowing that you don't need the escapes. Now the PHP and C# JSON are encoded the same. Why escape in PHP and hack in some escapes in C# when you don't need to escape in PHP.