# Call JavaScript function from Silverlight 4.0 application

Tags: javascript, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to call a function from a Silverlight application. It should be a very simple task to do but so far I am not getting the result that I am looking for.

This is my Silverlight code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("SayHello", new string[] { "Salut!" });
    }
```

And this is the JavaScript code :

```
   function SayHello(theid) {
        alert(eval(theid));
        var divStatusDiv = document.getElementById("divStatus");
        divStatusDiv.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
    }
```

The alert message always show "undefined" but when I press "OK" the colour of that DIV gets changed to Red as it should be.

Why am I getting "Undefined" all the time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the json that can be passed properly instead of just passing along an array like that. You can simply return "Salut!" instead of new string[] { "Salut!" } or you can create the json array for the string array you have.

Comment: How can I create json array in C# ? I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c is this what I need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Silverlight, but if `theid` has value `"Salut!"` inside of `SayHello`, then you cannot `eval` it, since it is a string of text, not code. You should change the line `alert(eval(theid));` to just `alert(theid);`.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. Undefined is what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
alert(eval(theid.value));
```

Comment: Also try to avoid using eval for both performance and code injection implications.

Comment: I don't think eval is a good idea, but please note that the arg is passed as an array of strings.