# Thrift supports JSON in C++ and Java, is C# support floating around somewhere?

Tags: c#, json, thrift

As the question asks, is there any know C# support for writing (don't care about reading) JSON via Thrift.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create JSON string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

C# JSON support is marked complete as of Thrift 0.9.1, as seen here:
http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/LibraryFeatures

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a Thrift C# api, a lot of it is associated with Cassandra

http://www.ridgway.co.za/archive/2009/11/06/net-developers-guide-to-getting-started-with-cassandra.aspx

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples#C.23

Comment: I don't see anything here regarding JSON and C#