# Cleaning strings to be valid JSON values

Tags: c#, json

I want to clean strings that are retrieved from a database.

I ran into this issue where a property value (a name from a database) had an embedded TAB character, and Chrome gave me an invalid TOKEN error while trying to load the JSON object.

So now, I went to http://www.json.org/ and on the side it has a specification.  But I'm having trouble understanding how to write a cleanser using this spec:

*string*

- ""
- " *chars* "

*chars*

- *char*
- *char*  *chars*

*char*

- any-Unicode-character-
  except-"-or--or-
  control-character
- \"
- \\
- /
- \b
- \f
- \n
- \r
- \t
- \u four-hex-digits

Given a string, how can I "clean" it such that I conform to this spec?

Specifically, I am confused: does the spec allow TAB (0x0900) characters?  If so, why did Chrome given an invalid TOKEN error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe what you are looking for it shows how to use the JavaScriptSerializer class in C#.

[How to create JSON String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c)

Answer (score 13):

Tab characters (actual `0x09`, not escapes) cannot appear inside of quotes in JSON (though they are valid whitespace outside of quotes).  You'll need to escape them with `\t` or `\u0009` (the former being preferable).

json.org says an unescaped character of a string must be:

> Any UNICODE character except " or \ or
>   control character

Tab counts as a control character.