# Make JSONP file in C#

Tags: c#, json, jsonp

I'm working with a object in C#.

```
 public class City
   {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string label { get; set; }
   }
```

I need to create a JSONP file. I hope to get something like this

```
Places({"id": 1, "label": "London"}, {"id": 2, "label": "Paris"})
```

I tried use

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();  ´
JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText("myJson.json"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(file, string.Format("{0}({1})", "Places", s.Serialize(places)));
    file.Close();
}
```

But my result file is this:

```
"Places([{\"id\":1,\"label\":\"London\"}, {\"id\":2,\"label\":\"Paris\"}])"
```

And this result does not working for my for the ' \" ' chars

Comment: `Places({"id": 1, "label": "London"}, {"id": 2, "label": "Paris"})` is **not** JSONP, as it contains 2 separate JSON objects with no containing array.

Comment: Please tell us how you are inspecting your final result (the one that contains `\"` escape sequences).

Comment: What is your intended use of the "JSONP file"? Making a JSONP *file* would be a highly unusual use of JSONP.

Comment: I want to store the file in a bucket

Comment: What's wrong with JSON and a CORS policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serializing your original data as JSON twice so result is JSON containing string which itself is JSON.

You should simply do string concatenation of JSON with suffix/prefix as shown for example in [How can I manage ' in a JSONP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431731/how-can-i-manage-in-a-jsonp-response):

```
var jsonpPrefix = "Places"  + "(";
var jsonpSuffix = ")";
var jsonp = 
    jsonpPrefix + 
    s.Serialize(places) + 
    jsonpSuffix);
```

The easiest way to write it to file is just `File.WriteAllText("myJson.jsonp", jsonp)`.

Alternatively instead of constructing string first just write it directly to file

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myJson.jsonp"))  
{
    sw.Write("Places(");
    sw.Write(s.Serialize(places));
    sw.Write(")"
}
```

Side note: saving JSONP to file is somewhat strange as it usually just send as response to cross-domain AJAX request - so make sure you really need JSONP and not just JSON.