# Creating a specific JSON format

Tags: c#, json

I'm attempting to create a JSON request to send to email service GetResponse to add a contact to a mail campaign.

The format I'm trying to achieve is for [add_contact](https://github.com/GetResponse/DevZone/tree/master/API#add_contact)

```
[
    "API_KEY",
    {
        "campaign"  : "CAMPAIGN_ID",
        "action"    : "action_value",
        "name"      : "name_value",
        "email"     : "email_value",
        "cycle_day" : cycle_day_value,
        "ip"        : "ip_value",
        "customs"   : [
            {
                "name"      : "name_1_value",
                "content"   : "content_1_value"
            },
            {
                "name"      : "name_2_value",
                "content"   : "content_2_value"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Following [How to create JSON string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp) I contructed this setup

```
private class AddContactRequest
{
    public string campaign { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int cycle_day { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
}
```

And filled this like so

```
AddContactRequest add = new AddContactRequest();
add.campaign = campaignID;
add.action = action
add.name = contact_name;
add.email = email;
add.cycle_day = cycle_day;
add.ip = ip_value;

string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(add);
```

Here *json* is as expected

```
{"campaign":"my_test_campaign","action":"standard","name":"Test Name","email":"test@example.com","cycle_day":0,"ip":"10.1.0.5"}
```

What I don't know is how to properly add the `API_KEY` string to the front of it.

How can I alter this to add the `API_KEY` to the front of it without a property name attached to it, ideally using `JavaScriptSerializer()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is create a collection of type `object` and pass `"API_KEY"` as the first entry and your `add` object as the second entry.

```
AddContactRequest add = new AddContactRequest();
add.campaign = campaignID;
add.action = action
add.name = contact_name;
add.email = email;
add.cycle_day = cycle_day;
add.ip = ip_value;

List<object> SerializedThingy = new List<object>
{
   "API_KEY",
   add
};

string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(SerializedThingy);
```

Comment: Perfect. You taught me something new today.

Comment: Also... look into a better json serializer.  http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, it looks like they're wrapping the JSON object in a proprietary fashion.  JSON needs to start with a '{', not a '['.  I would try something like this:

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(SerializedThingy);
string req = "[ \"API_KEY\", " + json + " ]";
```