# Create a JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I'm trying to create an object to be returned as JSON for my REST Web Service.

I wish to get something returned like this:

```
{
    "message": [
    {
        "name": "whatever.bmp"
    }
    ],
    "errors": null,
    "FileInflected": 0,
    "path": "C:\thepath"
}
```

So, how can I change the class (eFileOutput) in C#?

How can I change the class I have below?

Currently I'm able to create similar output like this:

```
{
  "message": "Hello World",
  "errors": null,
  "FileInfected": 0,
  "path": "C:\bla bla..."
}
```

and my C# class is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
    public class eFileOutput
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string message { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string errors { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Int32 FileInfected { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string path { get; set; }
    }
```

Tks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create JSON string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classes that represent the JSON you've stated:

```
public class Message
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public List<Message> message { get; set; }
    public object errors { get; set; }
    public int FileInflected { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyObject
{
    message = new List<Message>
    {
        new Message {name = "whatever.bmp"}
    },
    FileInflected = 0,
    path = @"c:\thepath"
});
```

Edit (thanks to devzero): Then you can serialize using Newtonsoft (my favorite) or JavaScriptSerializer as stated here: [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

Comment: Added an edit that actually produces the correct JSON with values from above into the json variable.

Comment: Tks a lot, this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Message Message { get; set; }

    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }

    public int FileInflected { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    //Whatever you want
}
```

and if You want to serialize member as camelCase, describe like this:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, jsonSerializerSettings);
```