# How to post a numeric value in c#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to use HTTPclient to post to a 3rd party api and get a response.  I'm able to post to the api but the problem i'm having is that the api requires the programid to be numeric.  Whenever i try to post with this code it throws it back telling me to make the programid numeric.

I'm at a loss as to how to send a numeric via a c#/.net post

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "accesstoken", authtoken },
       { "programid", programid},
       { "email", person.Email },
       { "thirdparty1", person.ID.ToString() }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = client.PostAsync("url", content);
    var responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: What is the type and value of `programid`? Also have you cased it correctly if the client api you are sending it to is case sensitive on the input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: right now the type is a string in c# but the value is 192926.  The api is expecting a numeric value.  but i am having trouble formating the value as a int and passing it into formurlencodedurl

Comment: can you use fiddler to see what you are passing, and determine if it is in fact a number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

maybe WebClient?

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "accesstoken", authtoken },
       { "programid", programid.ToString()},
       { "email", person.Email },
       { "thirdparty1", person.ID.ToString() }
    };

                var param = string.Join("&", values.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value).ToArray());

                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                string HtmlResult = client.UploadString(URI, "POST", param);
            }
```

just make sure you aren't passing any funny url routing characters like ? or &