# Create JSON Object Using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

Cytoscape.js JSON format is something like this :

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        shape: 'hexagon',
        'background-color': 'red',
        label: 'data(id)'
      }
    }],
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  elements: [
    { data: { id: 'a' }     },
    { data: { id: 'b' } },
    {
      data: {
        id: 'ab',
        source: 'a',
        target: 'b',
      }
    }]

});
```

I have been able to generate `elements` part myself, but I don't know how to generate other parts using C#. Should I do some kind of concatenation because other parts are not dynamic? If yes, how should I do that? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be using string concatenation. Create an object structure, then serialize that to JSON. See, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp.

Comment: That's a JS object, not JSON.  JSON element keys must be in quotes, and doesn't support things like `document.getElementById(...)`