# Int not getting displayed as string in JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to loop through the list of JSON objects and convert them into indexed JSON.

Below is the code I have written:

```
private string ItemsAsJson(List<string> jsonItemList)
{
    string ItemAsJson = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        string index = i.ToString();
        ItemAsJson += "{ " + index + " : " + jsonItemList[i] + "},";
    }
    return ItemAsJson;
}
```

But I get the object as below here:

```
{
    0: {
        "item_type": "Batch",
        "item_id": "82",
        "bill_item_name": "A TO Z",
        "quantity": "1",
        "inventory_id": "82",
        "individual_price": "2.90",
        "batch_no": "",
```

How do I convert the 0 in the above text to string ("0")?

Comment: You're writing out the literal JSON string, so put quotes around the 0?

Comment: Your entire containing data type is a string.  Where is the "object" you show in the second block coming from? is that coming directly from the `ItemsAsJson()` function?

Comment: An alternative is to do what is suggested in this answer.  Let the people who develop JSON serializers define the correct JSON syntax.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Never form your json manually, Use a json parser like [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to do it for you

Comment: Do you have to write the JSON yourself?  Json.NET will take care of the serialization details for you...

Comment: @PaulWalls I tried putting quotes, its not working still.

Comment: @axlj Yes, the json object is coming from ItemsAsJson().

Comment: @VivekJeevaKumar What's not working exactly? If you change your code to `ItemAsJson += "{ \"" + index + "\": " + jsonItemList[i] + "},";`, you'll get quotes around the index. If you are having a different problem, I'd recommend clarifying or asking a different question.

Answer (score -1):

The best answer would be to use a JSON parser library, like [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), and not parse the JSON manually.

If you for some reason decide to proceed with your method, you can add quotes around the index number by escaping the quote in the string like `\"`:

```
private string ItemsAsJson(List<string> jsonItemList)
{
    string ItemAsJson = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        string index = i.ToString();
        ItemAsJson += "{ \"" + index + "\": " + jsonItemList[i] + "},";
    }
    return ItemAsJson;
}
```

On a side note, if you are building a string like this, I would recommend using `StringBuilder` instead of `+=`:

```
private string ItemsAsJson(List<string> jsonItemList)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        builder.Append("{ \"");
        builder.Append(i);
        builder.Append("\":");
        builder.Append(jsonItemList[i]);
        builder.Append("},");
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```