# How to make json format valid?

Tags: javascript, json

I generated a string that contains a json in my C# codebehind, then I send it to the frontend to use in Javascript.
I want to use that json inside a function like `$.getJSON("<%=myJson%>")` but I'm getting some errors

I already tried to use the string directly since json is javascript code but it doesn't work. The console shows

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Then I tried `JSON.parse(myJson)` but it´s also not working. The console shows

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

This is how my Json string looks in codebehind:

```
"\"iss\":\"123123123\",\"exp\":123123,\"jti\":\"asdasdasdasd\",\"sub\":\"asdasdasdasd\",\"grants\":{\"identity\":\"John\",\"voice\":{\"incoming\":{\"allow\":true},\"outgoing\":{\"application_sid\":\"asdasdasdasd\"}}}}"
```

Then when I send it to Javascript in the frontend:

```
$.getJSON("
"iss":"123123123","exp":123123,"jti":"asdasdasdasd","sub":"asdasdasdasd","grants":{"identity":"John","voice":{"incoming":{"allow":true},"outgoing":{"application_sid":"asdasdasdasd"}}}}")
```

**UPDATE**
I fixed the json syntax in codebehind:

```
"{\"iss\":\"123123123\",\"exp\":123123,\"jti\":\"asdasdasdasd\",\"sub\":\"asdasdasdasd\",\"grants\":{\"identity\":\"John\",\"voice\":{\"incoming\":{\"allow\":true},\"outgoing\":{\"application_sid\":\"asdasdasdasd\"}}}}"
```

now I'm getting this error in javascript:

> $.getJSON('{"iss":"123123123","exp":123123,"jti":"asdasdasdasd","sub":"asdasdasdasd","grants":{"identity":"John","voice":{"incoming":{"allow":true},"outgoing":{"application_sid":"asdasdasdasd"}}}}')
>
> GET http://localhost:.... 400 (Bad Request)

I think it's because this function expects a url to access but how can I make it read my json string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you more quickly if you create a [mcve] that illustrates your problem. Note that this is NOT your entire project. It just needs to be a small example that you create from scratch that uses the concepts you are asking about. Be sure to read the link I gave for tips on how to create such an example.

Comment: That's not a valid json string, here's a minimal example `{"key":"value"}`

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky That's the problem he's trying to solve.

Comment: @Barmar adding quotes around it doesn't make it valid json either,that's why I give an example of a simple json `object`

Comment: Oh, I assumed he was using a C# library to create the JSON.

Comment: How are you creating the JSON in the first place? Use a standard library function rather than coding it yourself, there are many details that are easy to get wrong.

Comment: I got that json by decoding a token: `myJson = Jose.JWT.Decode(Token, secretKey);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes around the JSON in the JavaScript code, since JSON uses double quotes for the embedded strings.

```
$.getJSON('<%= myJson %>');
```

You also need to fix the code that's creating `myJson` in the first place, so that it's correctly formatted as JSON. See [How to create JSON string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

your json is wrong, you are missing a `{` at the beginning.
The following function should work:

```
JSON.parse(`{"iss":"123123123","exp":123123,"jti":"asdasdasdasd","sub":"asdasdasdasd","grants":{"identity":"John","voice":{"incoming":{"allow":true},"outgoing":{"application_sid":"asdasdasdasd"}}}}`)
```